# Spin-squeezing parameter for the coherent spin state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, squeezed-states

Let us consider the following definition of the spin-squeezing parameter
$$
\xi^2 = 2 \frac{\left( \Delta S_{\vec{n}_1} \right)_{\min}^2}{\left| \langle \vec{S} \rangle \right|},
$$
where the value in the numerator as a square of the minimal variance over all of the possible directions $\vec{n}_1$ such: $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{n}_0 = 0$, where $\vec{n}_0$ is a unit vector in the direction of the total spin, i.e.
$$
\vec{n}_0 = \langle \vec{S} \rangle / \lVert \langle \vec{S} \rangle \rVert .
$$

The coherent spin state (CSS) for $N$ spin 1/2 particles reads
$$
|\text{CSS}\rangle = \bigotimes_{l=1}^{N} \left[ \cos \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle _l + e^{i \phi} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} |1\rangle_l \right],
$$
where $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ are the eigenstates of $\sigma^z_l$. According to the [review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.2978.pdf), the parameter $\xi^2=1$ for the CSS. I would like to know whether it is also true for the opposite statement. Let us say, $\xi^2=1$ for some abstract state. Does it mean that this state has to be the CSS one? If not, could you please provide an example (and can we say anything about the state in this case)?